# Inno setup uninstaller doesnt delete rewritten registry values

Tags: registry, inno-setup

Inno setup uninstaller doesnt delete registry values when they are rewritten by other program although the values stay the sames as inno setup wrote them when installing. Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try deleting registry in Uninstall method, rather than using the flags in registry section?
Eg :

```
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
begin
  if CurUninstallStep = usUninstall then 
  begin  
   if RegValueExists(RegistryAccount, 'RegistryPath','RegistryValue') then
   begin
     RegDeleteValue(RegistryAccount, 'RegistryPath','RegistryValue');
   end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Sure i have the flags for uninsdeletevalue, look if for exemple when im installing the program the setup add the registry values that i want,  but when i use the program and it rewrites the registry values even with the sames values (no changes made in the values), and later i uninstall the program and it doesnt delete the values although they are with the sames values that the program installed.

Comment: You can overwrite the **CurUninstallStepChanged** method and remove registry as mentioned above. That should work.

Comment: Well i want to erase thoses values cause of they leave some visual element in the recycle bin right click part